# ghsystem, xfrac error in beamer frames

Tags: beamer, xfrac

In the following MWE, the second \sfrac{1}{2} (in a frame) throws an error

```
Font \OT1/cmr/m/n/3.83247=cmr4 at 4pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
```

There is no problem outside of the frame environment, or in the article environment. what is going wrong ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\RequirePackage{ghsystem}
\ghssetup{language=french}
\begin{document}


\(\sfrac{1}{2}\)

\begin{frame}
  \(\sfrac{1}{2}\)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. How are you compiling? I tried with xelatex from texlive2017.

Comment: with lualatex, but it turns out the error wasn't with polyglossia but with ghsystem, I edited the question to correct it.

Comment: Your new example also works fine for lualatex from texlive2017. Which tex distribution do you have?

Comment: @samcarter: it is quite possible that you have the fonts (e.g. from a previous pdflatex run), but check at the end of the log if bitmaps are used.

Comment: I'm using texlive 2017, updated as of this morning through tlmgr.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer. What should I look for in the log ?

Comment: My comment was for samcarter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with the font declarations in beamer. The issue has been resolved in the sources (https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/408 last two comments) but isn't in the texsystems yet. You can add the declarations like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}%
     {<3><4><5>cmr5<6><7><8><9><10><12>gen*cmr%<-- added cmr5
      <10.95>cmr10%
      <14.4>cmr12%
      <17.28><20.74><24.88><29.86><35.83><42.99><51.59>cmr17}{}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
 {<3><4><5>cmbx5<6><7><8><9>gen*cmbx%
  <10><10.95>cmbx10%
  <12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88><29.86><35.83><42.99><51.59>cmbx12%
  }{}

\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \(\sfrac{1}{2}\)
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your fix doesn't seem to work with the error when loading ghsystem.

Comment: Then you need similar code for the bold font, I added it.

Comment: It's working now, thanks. Should it soon hit the texlive mirrors ?